# The difference between alligned and indent line wrap in notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++

Already tried both, but I couldn't see any difference at all

> Align or alignment is a term used to describe how text is placed on the screen. For example, left-aligned text creates a straight line of text on the left side of the page (like this paragraph). Text can be aligned along the edge of a page, cell, div, table, or another visible or non-visible line.

**aligned** line wrap in notepad ++ seems different from the definition of align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Aligned` wrap the lines and make the following lines begining at the same column as the first line

[image]

- `Indent` add a tabulation in front of lines

[image]